# Non-hashable static arguments are not supported using JAX cond

Tags: python, jax

Here is a simplified version of my JAX program:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax
from functools import partial
from jax import jit

def main():
    N = 3
    x = jnp.ones((4, 5))
    a = True

    answer = jax.lax.cond(a, run_true, run_false, N, x)
    print(answer)


@partial(jit, static_argnames=["N"])
def run_true(N, x):
    return x.reshape((1, 4, 5)) * jnp.ones((N, 4, 5))

@partial(jit, static_argnames=["N"])
def run_false(N, x):
    return jnp.zeros((N, 4, 5))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting the following error when I run the above code:

`ValueError: Non-hashable static arguments are not supported, as this can lead to unexpected cache-misses. Static argument (index 0) of type <class 'jax.interpreters.partial_eval.DynamicJaxprTracer'> for function run_true is non-hashable.`

This doesn't make sense to me because both `run_true` and `run_false` are jittable functions.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

If I rewrite the code to be the following it works fine, but I need to use the jax.lax.cond inside of a jitted function so this is not a solution

```
if a:
    answer = run_true(N, x)
else:
    answer = run_false(N, x)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```py
answer = jax.lax.cond(a, partial(run_true, N), partial(run_false, N), x)
```

The reason is that any scalar or array argument passed to `cond` will automatically become traced, and traced arguments cannot be passed to a function that expects a static argument. The way to fix this is to avoid `N` being traced in the first place.